# Use jQuery to show a hidden div only when a certain div gets inserted dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a hidden div that I want shown only when a certain div gets inserted into the DOM dynamically via AJAX.

So the code is set up like:

```
<div>
    <div>hello</div>
    <div class="test">hello2</div>  <-- Class (.test) gets inserted dynamically. Initially it won't be there.
    <div>hello3</div>
</div>
<div class="hidden" style="display:none">hidden content here</div>
```

JS

```
$.ready(function() {
    if ($('div').hasClass('.test')) {
        $('.hidden').insertAfter( $( '.test' ) ).show();
    }
});
```

Not working, however. Nothing gets shifted. Anything wrong with the code?

Edit: AJAX code

```
// Poll Process Successfully
function poll_process_success(data) {
        jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
                //$('#polls-' + poll_id).replaceWith(data);

         var html ='<div class="first-block vote-submitted"><h2>Thanks for your vote!</h2></div><form id="poll_qst_form" class="second-block comment-block">';
                     html = html+'<input type="text" name="name" id="poll_name" placeholder="Your name" required>' ;
             <!--html = html+'<input type="email" name="email" id="poll_email" placeholder="Your email" required>' ;-->
             html = html+'<textarea name="comment" id="poll_comment" class="text poll_comment" placeholder="Let Kina and Ken know your feedback and questions!" required></textarea>' ;
             html = html+'<input type="button" class="Buttons" onclick="send_comment()" id="com_bnt" value="send">';
             html = html+'</form>' ;
         $('#polls-' + poll_id).replaceWith(html);


                if(pollsL10n.show_loading) {
                        $('#polls-' + poll_id + '-loading').hide();
                }
                if(pollsL10n.show_fading) {
                        $('#polls-' + poll_id).fadeTo('def', 1);
                        set_is_being_voted(false);
                } else {
                        set_is_being_voted(false);
                }
        });
}
```

Comment: can you put up a fiddle?

Comment: Your code runs once only at DOM ready time, never again. Dynamic content will be loaded later.

Comment: you said in your question you are adding div dynamically and you are adding `p` tag ?

Comment: That ready function is not valid (you need to set the handler). Also jQuery cannot listen for dynamically created elements like that, you may either need to use a plugin or a custom event that fires when you create something

Comment: That should not be `$.ready`. Use this shortcut instead `$(function(){ YOUR CODE HERE});`.

Comment: you can use success call instead of document ready function since the content not added on the load so far i understood.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update 1:**

As the div is dynamically loaded, you need to hook into your Ajax code and run at that point.

```
   $.ajax({
      // Your ajax settings here
   }).done(function(){
        if ($('div.test').length) {
            $('.hidden').insertAfter( $( '.test' ) ).show();
        }
   });
```

**Alternatives:**

You can also hook into the global Ajax completion handler (which fires after every single Ajax load):

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(function() {
        if ($('div.test').length) {
            $('.hidden').insertAfter( $( '.test' ) ).show();
        }
});
```

or use a timer to check regularly (e.g. 1 second in this example) for the change.

```
setInterval(function(){
     if ($('div.test').length) {
         $('.hidden').insertAfter( $( '.test' ) ).show();
     }
 }, 1000);
```

**Other issues.**

A DOM ready handler should look like:

```
$(function() {
    if ($('div.test').length) {
        $('.hidden').insertAfter( $( '.test' ) ).show();
    }
});
```

Or the long-winded

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if ($('div.test').length) {
        $('.hidden').insertAfter( $( '.test' ) ).show();
    }
});
```

Note: You also do not specify a leading "." in `hasClass` as it assumes it is a class name.

Note: You do not need `hasClass` as you can just check for the length of a jQuery selector result, in this case *of any div with `class="test"`* e.g. using `div.test`.

Comment: Sorry about the confusion. The class of `.test` gets added dynamically via AJAX. So initially, that class won't be there. I tried your code, but it didn't affect anything.

Comment: None of the current answers will help with dynamic loading... Will update shortly

Comment: Yeah, I tried the other ones too. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I'm trying out your updated code right now, but I'm a bit confused as to what settings I need to put in for the ajax settings. I see the list of settings [here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/), but I'm just trying to move a div around so which settings would I need to insert?

Comment: If you show your existing Ajax code, that loads that div, it will be a lot easier :)

Comment: This is a lot harder than I thought. I'm actually using a WordPress plugin called WP-Polls and once someone has voted on a poll, he gets shown a 'thank you' message + comment form. That is the point where I'd like to insert the hidden div. I was just digging through the plugin files and found two that I thought were relevant. Here's [one](http://pastebin.com/b3kViC3m), and here's the [other](http://pastebin.com/nFJKAwcL). I think the line you're looking for is line 144 of the first file which I pasted into the post above. I could be wrong, though.

Comment: @J82: The simplest alternative is probably to listen for the `ajaxComplete` event as mentioned earlier. I have added a simple code example for you.

Comment: Awesome! The Ajax completion handler method worked well. However, there is one issue. The hidden div contains an [HTML5 audio player](http://sjward.org/jplayer-for-wordpress/) and once the hidden div shows after the Ajax load, the play buttons stop working. Is this a whole new can of worms? Something I should open up a new topic for?

Comment: I would need to see the code in question, but that does sound like a new question. It may just need appropriate *delegated* event handlers.

Comment: I've decided to go with the timer method because the Ajax completion handler method wasn't loading up the hidden div on refresh after a user has voted (users are logged by IP and can only vote once) since there is no Ajax call being made. Through some research, it looks like I have to attach the event handlers again after the AJAX call completes, or use event delegation. Not quite grasping the concept =/ If you can take a look, I'd appreciate it. I've opened up a Q [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26123839/moving-html5-players-through-the-dom-with-setinterval-players-stop-working).

Answer (score 2):

If you have no access to the ajax code as per @TrueBlueAussies' answer, <strike>you can listen to some sort of [mutation event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Mutation_events).</strike>

[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ews315ke/3/)

```
$(document).bind('DOMNodeInserted', function(e) {
    if($('.test').length) {
        $('.hidden').show();
    }
});
```

**Update**

Mutation events are deprecated, you should use the MutationObserver instead.

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ews315ke/5/)

Comment: This worked! However, in that link, it says that it's deprecated. How much longer do you think it'd be until it doesn't work anymore? The good thing is that the site I'm working on will only be up for a limited time.

Comment: I just noticed that it was deprecated, so I updated with the prefered way to do it.

Comment: After I put in the code, I started getting a ton of errors in my console: http://i.imgur.com/aVhVFF5.jpg This happened both times when I tried it with Mutation and MutationObserver. I do have [this player](http://sjward.org/jplayer-for-wordpress/) loading in the new hidden div. I noticed that they stop working (playing music) too. Would you have any idea how I can get this to work?

Comment: @J82 I'm not terribly familiar with MutationObserver. It might be that you need to decrease the scope of the target query selector.

Comment: Actually, sorry about that. The code I was using was wrong. I actually appended your MutationObserver code to the old Mutation Event code like an idiot. Now I cleared out the Mutation Event code; however, now the hidden div is not even being moved. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: @J82: You may want to check the support requirements as `MutationObserver` is *very* new to some browsers: http://caniuse.com/#feat=mutationobserver We can't use it here as it is IE11 only.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie Ah, darn. Yeah, this probably wouldn't be an ideal solution, then.

Answer (score 0):

- it should be `$(document).ready`, not `$.ready`.
- it should be `hasClass('test')`, not `hasClass('.test')`.

Corrected code:

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p7fd4y9n/1/).

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    if ($('p').hasClass('test'))
    {
        $('.hidden').insertAfter($('.test')).show();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply Change following code :

```
$.ready(function() {
    if ($('div').hasClass('.test')) {
        $('.hidden').insertAfter( $( '.test' ) ).show();
    }
});
```

To

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if ($('div').hasClass('test')) {
        $('.hidden').insertAfter( $( '.test' ) ).show();
    }
});
```

**[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ym0nwuLt/)**

Answer (score 0):

Try [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/fge72ma9/5/)

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    if ($('div').hasClass('test')) {
        $('.hidden').insertAfter( $( '.test' ) ).show();
     }
});
```